# Using MailChimp for .NET sending mails to bcc

Tags: c#, .net, mailchimp

I'm using MailChimp for .NET sending mails, but the wrapper for the recipient doesn't contain a type, which the is necessary for sending massmails.

```
                MailChimp.Types.Mandrill.Messages.Recipient recipient = new MailChimp.Types.Mandrill.Messages.Recipient(member.EMail, member.Name);
```

Is it me who has missed something?

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from [MailChimp](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-create-a-new-campaign/). Scroll down to "Tips for creating your HTML Campaign".

> MailChimp does not use a BCC field as each recipient on your list is hidden from all other recipients on your list. We deliver a completely separate copy of your email to each recipient on your list, allowing you to personalize your content for each recipient, track clicks and opens, and address each email to the recipient's name.

Comment: Yes but the entity recipient has the following fields Name, EMail, Type where type can be To, CC, BCC and the thes i have performed using the .net wrapper displays all recipients in the to field

Comment: Which wrapper are you using? Perhaps it was added to the wrapper class. If you have the source you can check if it's actually being sent in an API call. The only email type I can find is to set html or plain text.

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/danesparza/MailChimp.NET/ which is still in active development and has 2.0 support.

Comment: Does github.com/danesparza/MailChimp.NET support using mandrill, cant find methods for send anywhere

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I'd add a feature request for it.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use MCAPI.NET and changed the source adding a attribute to Recipient with name "to".

Setting this attribute to value "BCC" solved the problem.

Note : MailChimp is a Newsletter sending software where Mandrill is a transactional mail sending component.